# What is the easiest-to-explain way to read a QR Code?

Tags: qr-code

What is the easiest way to teach/enable someone else to read a QR Code?

Please notice, I'm not asking how to read a QR Code. I know there's a lot of apps to do it.
I'm asking what is the easiest way to enable someone else, perhaps someone without much technical knowledge, to scan a QR Code?

For example, this would be great if it actually worked:
http://www.labnol.org/software/scan-qr-code-with-google/27955/

It does not require downloading an app, therefore it's easier to show someone how to do it.
Unfortunately, for the 2 android phones I tried that on, it did not work. (there was no image search option as described in the post)

Is the easiest way really to have someone download an app and run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you need to use a QR Code Reader. There is no way around that. You can't teach some to read QR's, but you can show them the proper way of using such an app. Most of the readers have built in dummy instructions - such as center the code in the picture,  how far away to get a good reading and other useful tidbits. Besides if they can take a picture with the device,  they can read a QR Code.

So to finish off,  yes the easiest way is to have an app installed,  unless your (their)  device has one natively installed

Comment: Yes, of course a QR Code Reader is necessary. I was hoping for some built-in by default app that I simply was unaware of. I hope my question didn't imply that I want to teach them how to visually decode a QR code with their eyes... this is the android SE after all. :)

Comment: I understood what you meant. There are a few camera apps,  I don't know the names, that when a QR code is front of the lens it will switch to reader mode.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just download an app and run it.  You can't visually look at a QR code and decode it with your brain.

Comment: Ask a silly question, get a silly answer.

Comment: This is the answer and +1. Google Goggles is free and scans QR codes. If a person can't be taught to download and open one single app they probably have no need for QR codes.  Otherwise you'd need some weird brain powers to interpret QR codes without a device.